# How to change border color within if statement?

Tags: flutter

I'am trying to change the border color by checking what type of priority it is,
if it's a low priority then the color should be green, if the priority is normal the color should be blue and if its high priority the color should be red.

Here is how I thought this code should work(it isn't working). How do I create if statements inside of definition of a border? Are there any other ways to change it?

```
 border: 
        if(task.priority == "Low"){
        Border(
      left: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.green),
      ),
      }
          if(task.priority == "Normal"){
    Border(
    left: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.blue),
    ),
    }
        if(task.priority == "High"){
    Border(
    left: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.red),
    ),
    }
```

Comment: `border: Border(
    left: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: getColorForPriority(task.priority)),
    )`

Comment: How do I define method GetColorForPriority()? I Tried     Color getColorForPriority(task){
    if(task.priority == "Low"){
      return Colors.green
    } and it didn't work

Comment: Never mind, got it working. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can have a single Border  widget with the color property calling a function which has these if else statements and setting it accordingly!
Dont forget to add the assignment statement in a setstate() 
Function.

Answer (score 0):

What OP is asked for can be done by moving the `if` statement to the beginning of the `build` method:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  var borderColor = Colors.green;
  if(task.priority == "Normal") borderColor = Colors.blue;
  if(task.priority == "High") borderColor = Colors.red;
    ...
  return SomeWidget (
         ...
      border: Border(
          left: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: borderColor),
      )
  ) 
}
```